# time() not using vdso?

Tags: linux, libc, vdso

I write a program，use time() function,

When I gdb it ：

```
[VM_241_149_tlinux ~/test]$ gdb ./testsys_d -q
Reading symbols from /data/home/youngxiao/test/testsys_d...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b __GI_time
Function "__GI_time" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (__GI_time) pending.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /data/home/youngxiao/test/testsys_d 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7345770 in time () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.149.tl1.6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-4.tl1.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-4.tl1.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7345770 in time () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000400671 in main ()
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function time:
=> 0x00007ffff7345770 <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00007ffff7345774 <+4>:     mov    $0xffffffffff600400,%rax
   0x00007ffff734577b <+11>:    callq  *%rax
   0x00007ffff734577d <+13>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00007ffff7345781 <+17>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.

ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

we can see the time() use vsyscall，not use vdso，why?

I also test gettimeofday() , it use vdso...